# undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I am pretty new to ror, and I run into some issue with my application:

I have a ticket model and a comment model,

```
    class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content, :title, :user, :priority, :category, :status
      validates_presence_of :content, :title, :category
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
    end

    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content, :ticket_id, :user
      belongs_to :ticket
    end
```

Now I want to send a mail when a comment is created:
In comment controller:

```
      def create
        @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

       respond_to do |format|
         if @comment.save

           TicketMailer.ticket_commented(@comment).deliver

           format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfull created.' }
          format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
      end
    end
```

Then in mailer:

```
    class TicketMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: "helpdesk@testing.com"

    def ticket_commented(comment)
       @comment = comment
        @ticket = Ticket.find_by_id(@comment.id)

       mail(:to => @comment.user, :subject => 'New comment')
     end

   end
```

But when I try to call

```
<%= @ticket.title %>
```

In view, I got this error: `undefined method`title' for nil:NilClass`

Did I do something wrong? Or how can I pass @ticket into the mailer correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mailer you're trying to find a ticket by providing the id of a comment, change the line `@ticket = Ticket.find_by_id(@comment.id)` to `@ticket = @comment.ticket`

Comment: Thanks man, totally works! I didn't know I can do @comment.ticket even comment belongs to ticket.

Comment: Glad I could help, please have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html